# HBase MemStore and BlockCache exceeds the threshold

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I want to connect spark jobs with my remote HBase. I got the following jars:

> --jars spark-hbase-connector_2.10-1.0.3.jar,hbase-shaded-protobuf-3.4.1.jar,hbase-0.90.3.jar

So I am importing protobuff, connector to HBase (https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector) and hbase itself. However I get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Current heap configuration for MemStore
> and BlockCache exceeds the threshold required for successful cluster
> operation. The combined value cannot exceed 0.8. Please check the
> settings for hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit and
> hfile.block.cache.size in your configuration.

In the hbase-0.90.3.jar, the hbase-default.xml specifies

> hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.upperLimit
>     0.4
>     Maximum size of all memstores in a region server before new
>       updates are blocked and flushes are forced. Defaults to 40% of heap

and

> hfile.block.cache.size
>       0.2
>       
>           Percentage of maximum heap (-Xmx setting) to allocate to block cache
>           used by HFile/StoreFile. Default of 0.2 means allocate 20%.
>           Set to 0 to disable.

0.4+0.2 isn't more than 0.8. Is there anything that can cause this error?
In my code I specify

> sparkConf.set("spark.hbase.host", "remoteHost")

The port to zookeeper in hbase-defaults is 2181 and it is the same in my hbase on remote server.

Thanks in advance